# How to add animated top menu on blogger

Tags: jquery, blogger

I am trying to make my top menu animated when scrolling down. 
I am using this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/JJ8Jc/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $('#menu-wrapper').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        if($('#menu-wrapper').data('size') == 'big')
        {
            $('#menu-wrapper').data('size','small');
            $('#menu-wrapper').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            },600);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($('#menu-wrapper').data('size') == 'small')
        {
            $('#menu-wrapper').data('size','big');
            $('#menu-wrapper').stop().animate({
                height:'100px'
            },600);
        }  
    }
});
</script>
```

But somehow is not working, any ideas?

The website is www.rockandblossom.com

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

On your website, I don't see a menu with the id `#menu-wrapper` but I see a menu with the class .menu-wrapper. So change `#menu-wrapper` in `.menu-wrapper` in your code and it will work.